# Query to find idle time i.e GPS lat long showing same coordinates within 15 minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql, gps, postgis, latitude-longitude

My GPS table in postgres has the schema with four fields as userid (int), latitude (float8), longitude (float8), recordedtime (time stamp).
For every user, we get 2 records for every minute.

Need a query to find the users who spent more then 15 minutres in same GPS lat long value?

the sample records could be

```
Userid, Latitiude, Longitude, recordedtime 
============================================
'ID1',12.089475408,76.089890,2019-11-24 19:10:01
'ID1',12.089475408,76.089890,2019-11-24 19:10:31
'ID1',12.089475408,76.089890,2019-11-24 19:11:01
'ID1',12.089475408,76.089890,2019-11-24 19:10:31
'ID1',12.089475408,76.089890,2019-11-24 19:12:01
'ID1',12.089475408,76.089890,2019-11-24 19:10:31
....
```

..

Could anyone please provide the required query?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't even have 15 minutes time span... Better sample table data, and also the expected result would make the problem easier to understand.

Comment: The sample data as below. The ID1 has spent more than 15 
minutes at lat long 13.082240,80.205480.  

So When i run the query, i should get ID1.  
  
'ID1',13.082240,80.205480 ,2019-11-24 19:10:01  

'ID1',13.082240,80.205480 ,2019-11-24 19:12:01  

'ID1',13.082240,80.205480 ,2019-11-24 19:14:01  

'ID1',13.082240,80.205480 ,2019-11-24 19:26:01  

'ID1',13.082240,80.205480 ,2019-11-24 19:30:01  

'ID1',13.082560,80.202890 ,2019-11-24 19:32:01  

'ID2',13.082240,80.205480 ,2019-11-24 19:18:01  

'ID2',13.082240,80.205480 ,2019-11-24 19:28:01

Comment: The data is not realistic. The GPS coordinates will most likely be slightly different at each measurement so the group by lat/long is going to fail. Instead, one would look if the coordinates are all within a given distance tolerance from each other (10 cm? 1 meter? 10 meters?). In such case, using PostGIS is the way to go

Comment: Hi JGH, Thanks for the inputs. Yes, the lat long would vary if the user moves a bit. Let us say if the boundary is 50 meters with varying lat long, then could you please provide the query?  i.e the time spent if the user lat long is within 50 meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) might be what you're looking for.

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT userid,longitude,latitude,
    max(recordedtime)-min(recordedtime) AS timespent
  FROM t
  GROUP BY userid,longitude,latitude
) SELECT * FROM j
  WHERE timespent > interval '15 minute';

 userid | longitude | latitude  | timespent 
--------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 ID1    | 80.205480 | 13.082240 | 00:20:00
(1 Zeile)
```

Have you considered using [`PostGIS`](https://postgis.net/) to deal with your points? Your use case seems pretty simple, but very quickly you might find yourself struggling to perform geospatial operations in your data model that are already solved in PostGIS.

In case you're interested, this is what you should do to create a geometry column based on your GPS coordinates:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY;
UPDATE t SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),4326);
```

The value **4326** in the [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) function stands for the Reference System WGS84. Check which one suits your coordinates.

And this is how the query would look like:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT userid,geom,
    max(recordedtime)-min(recordedtime) AS timespent
  FROM t
  GROUP BY userid,geom
) SELECT userid,ST_AsText(geom),timespent FROM j
  WHERE timespent > interval '15 minute';

 userid |        st_astext         | timespent 
--------+--------------------------+-----------
 ID1    | POINT(80.20548 13.08224) | 00:20:00
(1 Zeile)
```

**Note**: As mentioned by @JGH, this use case assumes that the coordinates are *identical* in order to compute the time spent in certain location. Your coordinates have six decimal places, which gives you a precision of `0.111 m`. Long story short, if the coordinates deviate by a few meters it won't work. In PostGIS using [`ST_Buffer`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Buffer.html) you can easily create a buffer of a given size and with [`ST_Within`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html) you can check if one of your points is inside of the buffer. The query below should give an idea on how to do this:

(Buffer of 50 meters)

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT userid, recordedtime, geom,
    ST_Buffer(geom::GEOGRAPHY,50)::GEOMETRY AS buffer
  FROM t
) SELECT t.userid, max(t.recordedTime)-min(t.recordedTime) AS timespent 
  FROM t,j
  WHERE t.userid=j.userid AND ST_Within(t.geom,j.buffer) 
  GROUP BY t.userid
  HAVING max(t.recordedTime)-min(t.recordedTime) > INTERVAL '15 minute';

 userid | timespent 
--------+-----------
 ID1    | 00:22:00
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Thanks JIm Jones. Your comments added value to me to explore further in Postgis.

Comment: Was about to ask that and you provided the query. Thanks again. WIll test it.

Comment: JIm, One more column is needed. i.e Goem  location along with this query. 
With  given Geom location, the boundary of 50 meters and time spent > 15 minutes. 

Not all the geom location within the bounday need to be provided. 
Only the one geom location is needed and the other geom location can be ignored.
If the user spends more than 50 minutes in some other boundary, we need to report that 
geom location and NOT all the geom points WITHIN it  
  
geom   |userid | timespent  
--------+-------+-----------  
 ???    |ID1    | 00:22:00

Comment: you mean this?
`WITH j AS (
  SELECT userid, recordedtime, geom,
    ST_Buffer(geom::GEOGRAPHY,50)::GEOMETRY AS buffer
  FROM t
) SELECT t.userid, ST_AsText(buffer), max(t.recordedTime)-min(t.recordedTime) AS timespent
  FROM t,j
  WHERE t.userid=j.userid AND ST_Within(t.geom,j.buffer) 
  GROUP BY t.userid, buffer
  HAVING max(t.recordedTime)-min(t.recordedTime) > INTERVAL '15 minute';`

Comment: Just let me know, so that I can update the answer:)